# SQL Server : data import failed via flat file Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to upload a CSV file (comma delimited) to a SQL Server 2012 (vs 11.0.2100.60) table. I have created a table with *all* columns equal to `nvarchar(MAX)` for test purposes as I just want to get the data into the database just to test. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

> *Messages Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 2" returned status*
>   *value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters
>   had no match in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import and Export
>   Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source -
>   Book2_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Column 2]" failed
>   because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on
>   "Source - Book2_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Column
>   2]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on
>   the specified object of the specified component.  (SQL Server Import
>   and Export Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error
>   occurred while processing file
>   "C:\Users\shalinp\Desktop\MISO\junk\Book2.txt" on data row 3. (SQL
>   Server Import and Export Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1:
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on
>   Source - Book2_txt returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component
>   returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure. 
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)*

My file is large but I created a new file that only has the first 4 rows of data to test. Unfortunately stackoverflow does not let you upload a file so I can't provide it (correct me if I am mistaken?).

But here is a cut and paste of it:

```
1/1/2010,ARNLD HAZELTON BASE,HAZLTON HAZLTARNOL34_1 1 (LN/ALTW/ALTW),ACTUAL,1,($23.18)
1/1/2010,MANISTIQ_T1_T1_XF,MANISTIQ T1 T1 (XF/WEC/*),,1,($12.47)
1/1/2010,ONT-NYIS BASE,BECK2 BECK2GPACKAR_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK_BNIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK_ANIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); STLAWRE1 SAUND_MOSES1_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK2GNIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); STLAWRE1 SAUND_MOSES__1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO),ACTUAL,1,($6.05)
1/1/2010,PADDCK_TWNLINE FLO PADDCK_BLACKHWK,TOWNELIN TLR_PAD 1 (LN/ALTE/ALTE),PADDOCK-BLACKHAWK 138 (X-53),1,($3.06)
```

I suspect the failure is occurring in row 3, column 3, which has a long text string:

```
BECK2 BECK2GPACKAR_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK_BNIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK_ANIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); STLAWRE1 SAUND_MOSES1_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); BECK2 BECK2GNIAG_3_1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO); STLAWRE1 SAUND_MOSES__1 A (LN/ONT/NYISO)
```

That said, this is why I'm using type `nvarchar(max)`. In any case I appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: from the data you pasted, I am having a hard time telling where the row begins and where it ends... can you elaborate on that pls.

Comment: are you importing the data using the import wizard, or using a script

Comment: @SQLGuru - Thanks for your speedy response. So each row ends at the end of the dollar value. There should be a LF there.

Comment: @SQLGuru - I'm using the import wizard.

Comment: I also tried to replace the text string in row 3 column 3 with a hand written string that is equally long in length and I get the same error. I would have thought the *nvarchar(max)* type would have been sufficient?

Comment: this solves the problem = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212536/sql-server-import-wizard-fails-with-incomprehensible-message

Comment: No wonder Jim Rogers is short MSFT stock.

Comment: This link shows the solution to the problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212536/sql-server-import-wizard-fails-with-incomprehensible-message